# How to manage my own reviews and ratings in Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

Is there such an option in Mac App Store? I know in iTunes Store we can manage reviews and ratings in personal account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Mac App Store. On the Featured tab, in the right sidebar, there is a link called Account. Under Settings > Reviews and Ratings, click Manage. You can edit / delete your reviews there.

Comment: Not any more...
I don't see anywhere I can view or manage my reviews. Disturbing, so I'll stop reviewing apps.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS Mojave and later this is managed in the Account area that can be accessed at the bottom of the left sidebar. Once in the Account area, click on View Information and under Manage > Reviews and Ratings there will be a Manage link button.